# how to disable a spcific cgi page in apache?

Tags: apache-2.4, cgi, blocking

I have an Apache server that hosts multiple sites, one of them use CGI, one of them does not. While security scanning this non-CGI site was flagged in the tool for security review for a CGI page.

I am trying to block that page in Apache using the following methods, but it does not seem to work either way:

Testing in Apache site vhost:

```
<Location />
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi-bin/serve-boxcgi$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
</Location>
```

Testing in .htaccess for this site:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cgi-bin/serve-boxcgi$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

The site is PHP based. It does use PHP-fpm/fast-CGI configurations.
Please advise what I may be doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a certain site under a different virtual host in your sites-enabled you can try adding this to the site where you don't want php:

```
php_flag engine off
```